# Importing local library and files in an application

Tags: go, package

I'm new to Go (but not at programming), I love the language but I have a bit of trouble fully understanding the way I'm supposed to make internal libraries in an application through packages. For reference, getting external packages and then importing/using them is fine.

Let's say I'm making an application A.

```
/home/me/A/a.go (package main)
```

Then, I realize a.go start to be rather big, so I cut it into two parts

```
/home/me/A/a.go (package main)
/home/me/A/b.go (package main)
```

How am I supposed to import/include b.go from a.go to make its function available ?

As a continuation of the question, in the A I'm manipulation lots of objects O, so I figure it would be a lot better if I just give them their own package and encapsulate the functionalities in a public/exported api. How do I do that ?

I've tried creating `./lib/o.go` (package o) and `import lib/o` but I keep getting error like

```
./a.go:6: imported and not used: "o"
./a.go:43: undefined: o
```

I have no GOPATH in my env but I tried `export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/home/me/A` and it didn't change the result.

I've tried to read the article on "go layout" but it felt a bit too overwhelming at once and  I would really love a simpler explanation of that one "small" step I am trying to make

Thanks !

GOPATH/src/me/a/a.go:

```
package main

func main() {
        test()
}
```

GOPATH/src/me/a/test.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func test() {
        fmt.Println("test func !")
}
```

Exec:

```
$ go run a.go 
# command-line-arguments 
./a.go:4: undefined: test
```

EDIT: got my answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/qysy2bM_o1I

Either list all files in go run (`go run a.go test.go`) or use `go build` and run the resulting executable.

Comment: If both files are in the same directory they form one package. No import statements are needed to get symbols declared in different files of the same package.

Comment: @FUZxxl: could you look at the bare example I added at the end of my question ? I can't seem to get it working, I guess I'm doing something so obviously wrong it gets over me. Thanks

Comment: Answering myself, but got my answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/qysy2bM_o1I Either list all files in go run (`go run a.go test.go`) or use `go build` and run the resulting executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the Go build system while not following the necessaary required directory layouts. You will benefit a lot from reading [this document](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

In short, these are, wrt the go tool, the show stoppers:

- You *must* have a valid, exported GOPATH
- Package files with import path "example/foo" *must* be located in the `$GOPATH/src/example/foo` directory.

For more details please see the above linked article.

Comment: I've followed the doc there and I am able to load my library o from application a with paths `GOPATH/src/a/a.go` and `GOPATH/src/o/o.go`, that's working. Thanks ! However, I do not understand how I can "include" a file from the same package, eg how do I include from a the file b who is in `GOPATH/src/a/b.go` ? This is not a library, only a separation of code in multiple files. In the link you give they have two files in the streak package, how would `streak.go` include and use `oauth.go` ?

Comment: I don't understand how the information above answers the question of using, say a struct, in a file in the same directory as a.go